# Reputation/Privileges Inconsistencies

Tags: bug, reputation, privileges

Unfortunately I don't know how to reproduce this, but I have been getting incorrect notifications on my stackoverflow account regarding my reputation and access privileges. This has happened three times so far.

Most recently, I received a notification saying that I have gained the "comment everywhere" privilege. However, I do not yet have enough reputation to warrant this.

I've checked my account and reputation history and made sure that I didn't surpass 50 reputation and then get voted down somewhere, or some similar case.

[Screenshot here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rsmik.jpg)

Comment: If someone upvoted and "quickly" undid their vote, this can happen and won't be traced in your rep history.